# @RestController custom ResponseEntity - Jackson

Tags: json, spring, jackson, spring-data-rest

What i'm trying to achieve here is to get a custom response from the RequestMapping, below is the structure of the json which I'm trying to get in case of an array of objects:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "the message",
    "data": [{},{},...]
}
```

and the below in case of object

```
 {
        "error": false,
        "message": "the message",
        "data": {}
    }
```

The code is working fine but the problem is "data" will not always has an array, it may store an object, so what I tried is to create a custom POJO class which contains my custom response and when I want to annotate two attributes with same name i'm getting the below error

> Could not find acceptable representation

And what if I create another class which will contain the same attributes but with an JsonObject not with array, is there any better way to achieve this ?

Below are my classes :

```
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class JsonResponseObject<T> implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private boolean error;
    private String message ;
    @JsonProperty(value="data")
    private ArrayList<T> array;
    @JsonProperty(value="data")
    private Object object ;


    public JsonResponseObject() {

    }


    public boolean isError() {
        return error;
    }


    public void setError(boolean error) {
        this.error = error;
    }


    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }


    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }


    public ArrayList<T> getArray() {
        return array;
    }


    public void setArray(ArrayList<T> array) {
        this.array = array;
    }


    public Object getObject() {
        return object;
    }


    public void setObject(Object object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

}
```

UserJsonController.java :

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping(value = "/json")
public class UserJsonController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userDAO;

@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getUsers() {

    ArrayList<Users> entityList = (ArrayList<Users>) userDAO.findAll();

    JsonResponseObject<Users> jsonResponse = new JsonResponseObject<Users>();
    jsonResponse.setError(false);
    jsonResponse.setMessage("test"); 
    jsonResponse.setArray(entityList);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getUserByID(@PathVariable int id) {

    JsonResponseObject<Users> jsonResponse = new JsonResponseObject<Users>();
    jsonResponse.setError(false);
    jsonResponse.setMessage("test");
    jsonResponse.setObject(userDAO.findById(id).get());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

}}
```

---

Comment: Maybe you can use Jackson ability of Polymorphic deserialization in combination with overwritten covariant return types: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Comment: It seems like you're trying to send 200 OK responses even when you have an error. Don't. Just send back data, and if you need to signal an error, throw an exception, and annotate it (or use a ControllerAdvice) so that it generates an error response, with a proper error status code.

Comment: @NickRussler I'll check it

Comment: @JBNizet actually this is not the complete code and regarding exception yeah I have a ConstrollerAdvise,, the question is how to get a custom response if data found either found an array or object , but I need to use the same attribute name as shown with ``@JsonProperty(value="data")``